# what is different between &[&str] with &Vec<&str> in rust?

Tags: rust

When I do exercise in rustlings, I found that exercise:

```
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {}
```

i try to change function to

```
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &Vec<&str>) -> String {}
```

It also works properly, So my question is what is different between &[&str] with &Vec<&str> in rust? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's substitute the inner `&str` with `T`. Then `&[T]` is a **slice** of `T` and `&Vec<T>` is a **reference to a vector** of `T`.

When a function is defined to accept a `&[T]`, you can also pass a `&Vec<T>`. Another very common case is to declare a parameter as `&str`, as that allows you to directly pass, for example `&String`. This is known as [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion).

Comment: Thanks, which one is best for define it as parameter in function?

Comment: Usually `&[T]` is better, as it is more generic. If you have a `&Vec<T>` parameter, you can only pass a `&Vec<T>` value. If you are familiar with languages like Java or .NET, it's somewhat similar to using an interface, as opposed to a concrete class.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that pretty much all of the non-mutating methods on `Vec<T>` are [actually defined on `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods-%5BT%5D) (you can call them on `Vec` because method calls are another place where derefs implicitly happen). Therefore, taking a `&[T]` instead of a `&Vec<T>` is pretty much always preferable - it makes the function more flexible without losing any functionality.

Comment: Good point, @JoeClay

Comment: I understand what your said. when we use slice, it can accept slice also can accept reference just like &str and &String. Thanks.